# Which permission required to copy the file on SharePoint server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, sharepoint-permissions

On SharePoint server, I am trying to copy a file with Shared drive's folder through C# code. But its not get working shows in the logs 'Access denied'. The user credentials I used in code has Read/write/Read & Execute/Modify permission.  If I apply the Authenticated User permission it get work. Also, I don't want to apply the Everyone, Network, Authenticated User permission on the folder.

Can anyone please advise which SharePoint server account permission I have to use in the code and which permission I have to add on the folder so that file gets copy.

Comment: What do you mean by using “Shared drive”, “authenticated user”?  What for. Of authentication are you using and what version of SharePoint are you using.  This issue may be readily disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

At least, the account should have edit permission.

Comment: Account has edit permissions, but still not get working.